# the value of the form controls is empty string

Tags: angular, typescript

I am not getting the value of my form control in.ts file. The value is always null. The form is very simple. I have two from control Start date and end date. I am trying toi get the value of start date and end date in my back end .ts file. The calendar associated with these control is popping up, but does not show the dates in the calendar. The calendar is totally blank. Below is my html code:

```
<div class="headerDiv">
  <div class="headerTopBanner"></div>
  <div class="headerLogo">
      <div class="logo"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="headerBottomBanner">

  </div>
</div>
<div class="maxContent">
  <div *ngIf="!Loaded">
    <i class="loadingIconSearch fa fa-refresh fa-spin fa-4x fa-fw"></i> <span class="loadingIconSubSection">Loading</span>
  </div>
  <div *ngIf="Loaded" >
    <form id="RecProject">
      <fieldset>
    <div class="row"  >
      <div class="col-md-2">
        <mat-form-field >
          <input formControlName="startDate" matInput [matDatepicker]="picker" placeholder="Start Date">
          <mat-datepicker-toggle matSuffix [for]="picker"></mat-datepicker-toggle>
          <mat-datepicker #picker></mat-datepicker>
          <mat-error >Start date is Required</mat-error>
        </mat-form-field>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-2">
        <mat-form-field>
          <input formControlName="endDate" matInput [matDatepicker]="endpicker" placeholder="End Date">
          <mat-datepicker-toggle matSuffix [for]="endpicker"></mat-datepicker-toggle>
          <mat-datepicker #endpicker></mat-datepicker>
          <mat-error >End date is Required</mat-error>

        </mat-form-field>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-2">
        <mat-form-field (keydown.enter)="$event.preventDefault()" >
          <input matInput placeholder="Total Records" formControlName="totalRecords">
        </mat-form-field>
      </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-4">
    <div class="row margintop10">
        <div class="col-md-12">
        <mat-form-field (keydown.enter)="$event.preventDefault()" class="fullWidth">
          <input matInput placeholder="DB Name" formControlName="DBName">
        </mat-form-field>


</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-5 inputMargin">
  <button class="appBtn lineButton" (click) = "LoadData()" >
    Start Loading
    <span><i class="fa fa-map-marker"></i></span>
  </button>
</div>
</div>


      </fieldset>
    </form>
  </div>
```

My .ts code to read the values of startdate and end date is below:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { FormGroup, FormControl, Validators, FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import {RecLoadService} from '../shared/RecLoad.service';
import {RecLoadDataTypeModel} from '../Models/RecLoadData.model';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-Recload',
  templateUrl: './Recload.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./Recload.component.css']
})
export class RecloadComponent implements OnInit {
  public Loaded = true;
  DataUploaded = false;
  message = null;
  public RecLoadData:RecLoadDataTypeModel=null;


public startDate = new FormControl('', Validators.required);
public endDate = new FormControl('' , Validators.required);
  constructor(public service: RecLoadService) { }

   ngOnInit() {
  }




  LoadData() {
     if (!this.startDate.hasError('required') && !this.endDate.hasError('required')) {
            this.RecLoadData.startDate  = this.startDate.value;
            this.RecLoadData.endDate = this.endDate.value;
           this.service.UploadRecLoadData(this.RecLoadData).subscribe(() => {
              this.DataUploaded =true;
              this.message = 'Data uploaded Successfully';

           });



       }
 }


    }
```

When I run the code in chrome browser, the value of start date and end date is always empty strings. Also, the calendar associated with these controls is not showingany dates. Its totally blank. Below is the image:

[image]

any help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: Have you checked the console for any additional errors you may be getting?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

On Developing systems you gonna always have problems like this. So you need to find a way to solve for get paid, so that you can see the right part that you are having errors. so use some versioning to save your code and go without fear to attack it. The way to solve this, is to left just the part that matters at the point and make it simple as it can be, if you need examples and samples, if you search you may find.
Remember to always go testing your logic simple on building something, because is by building.

If you need more leaning you could find something on this documentation [Material form fields documentation](https://material.angular.io/components/form-field/overview)

Seems like a not helpful answer but if you see the point, this knowledge could answer not this problem but lots in the code road.

Try see all the console are trying to tell you, it means the IDE and the WEB console.

Comment: hope you can write some encouraging comments and please avoid references to getting paid or not. you are not paying them so make your peace.